# The Elements of the Periodic Table in Spanish

Tags: vocabulario-técnico, ciencia

I would like to know the elements of the periodic table in Spanish, because my parents do not know much about them. I want to be able to describe them a bit about the elements, but I have no background information about the elements.

I found this website called [vanderkrogt.net](http://www.vanderkrogt.net/elements/language.php?language=es), but it does not look reliable.

(I did recognize Oxygen with oxígeno.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here you have all of them:

> [image]
>
> <sub>(click to expand)</sub>

In a list:

1. **H**    →   hidrógeno (Hydrogen)
2. **He**   →   helio (Helium)
3. **Li**   →   litio (Lithium)
4. **Be**   →   berilio (Beryllium)
5. **B**    →   boro (Boron)
6. **C**    →   carbono (Carbon)
7. **N**    →   nitrógeno (Nitrogen)
8. **O**    →   oxígeno (Oxygen)
9. **F**    →   flúor (Fluorine)
10. **Ne**  →   neón (Neon)
11. **Na**  →   sodio (Sodium)
12. **Mg**  →   magnesio (Magnesium)
13. **Al**  →   aluminio (Aluminium)
14. **Si**  →   silicio (Silicon)
15. **P**   →   fósforo (Phosphorus)
16. **S**   →   azufre (Sulfur)
17. **Cl**  →   cloro (Chlorine)
18. **Ar**  →   argón (Argon)
19. **K**   →   potasio (Potassium)
20. **Ca**  →   calcio (Calcium)
21. **Sc**  →   escandio (Scandium)
22. **Ti**  →   titanio (Titanium)
23. **V**   →   vanadio (Vanadium)
24. **Cr**  →   cromo (Chromium)
25. **Mn**  →   manganeso (Manganese)
26. **Fe**  →   hierro (Iron)
27. **Co**  →   cobalto (Cobalt)
28. **Ni**  →   niquel (Nickel)
29. **Cu**  →   cobre (Copper)
30. **Zn**  →   cinc (Zinc)
31. **Ga**  →   galio (Gallium)
32. **Ge**  →   germanio (Germanium)
33. **As**  →   arsénico (Arsenic)
34. **Se**  →   selenio (Selenium)
35. **Br**  →   bromo (Bromine)
36. **Kr**  →   kriptón (Krypton)
37. **Rb**  →   rubidio (Rubidium)
38. **Sr**  →   estroncio (Strontium)
39. **Y**   →   ytrio (Yttrium)
40. **Zr**  →   circonio (Zirconium)
41. **Nb**  →   niobio (Niobium)
42. **Mo**  →   molibdeno (Molybdenum)
43. **Tc**  →   tecnecio (Technetium)
44. **Ru**  →   rutenio (Ruthenium)
45. **Rh**  →   rodio (Rhodium)
46. **Pd**  →   paladio (Palladium)
47. **Ag**  →   plata (Silver)
48. **Cd**  →   cadmio (Cadmium)
49. **In**  →   indio (Indium)
50. **Sn**  →   estaño (Tin)
51. **Sb**  →   antimonio (Antimony)
52. **Te**  →   teluro (Tellurium)
53. **I**   →   yodo (Iodine)
54. **Xe**  →   xenón (Xenon)
55. **Cs**  →   cesio (Caesium)
56. **Ba**  →   bario (Barium)
57. **La**  →   lantano (Lanthanum)
58. **Ce**  →   cerio (Cerium)
59. **Pr**  →   praseodimio (Praseodymium)
60. **Nd**  →   neodimio (Neodymium)
61. **Pm**  →   prometio (Promethium)
62. **Sm**  →   samario (Samarium)
63. **Eu**  →   europio (Europium)
64. **Gd**  →   gadolinio (Gadolinium)
65. **Tb**  →   terbio (Terbium)
66. **Dy**  →   disprosio (Dysprosium)
67. **Ho**  →   holmio (Holmium)
68. **Er**  →   erbio (Erbium)
69. **Tm**  →   tulio (Thulium)
70. **Yb**  →   yterbio (Ytterbium)
71. **Lu**  →   lutecio (Lutetium)
72. **Hf**  →   hafnio (Hafnium)
73. **Ta**  →   tántalo (Tantalum)
74. **W**   →   wolframio [o tungsteno](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/15801/1674) (Tungsten)
75. **Re**  →   renio (Rhenium)
76. **Os**  →   osmio (Osmium)
77. **Ir**  →   iridio (Iridium)
78. **Pt**  →   platino (Platinum)
79. **Au**  →   oro (Gold)
80. **Hg**  →   mercurio (Mercury)
81. **Tl**  →   talio (Thallium)
82. **Pb**  →   plomo (Lead)
83. **Bi**  →   bismuto (Bismuth)
84. **Po**  →   polonio (Polonium)
85. **At**  →   astato (Astatine)
86. **Rn**  →   radón (Radon)
87. **Fr**  →   francio (Francium)
88. **Ra**  →   radio (Radium)
89. **Ac**  →   actinio (Actinium)
90. **Th**  →   torio (Thorium)
91. **Pa**  →   protactinio (Protactinium)
92. **U**   →   uranio (Uranium)
93. **Np**  →   neptunio (Neptunium)
94. **Pu**  →   plutonio (Plutonium)
95. **Am**  →   americio (Americium)
96. **Cm**  →   curio (Curium)
97. **Bk**  →   berkelio (Berkelium)
98. **Cf**  →   californio (Californium)
99. **Es**  →   einsteinio (Einsteinium)
100. **Fm** →   fermio (Fermium)
101. **Md** →   mendelevio (Mendelevium)
102. **No** →   nobelio (Nobelium)
103. **Lr** →   lawrencio (Lawrencium)
104. **Rf** →   rutherfordio (Rutherfordium)
105. **Db** →   dubnio (Dubnium)
106. **Sg** →   seaborgio (Seaborgium)
107. **Bh** →   bohrio (Bohrium)
108. **Hs** →   hassio (Hassium)
109. **Mt** →   meitnerio (Meitnerium)
110. **Ds** →   darmstadtio (Darmstadtium)
111. **Rg** →   roentgenio (Roentgenium)
112. **Cn** →   copernicio (Copernicium)

Comment: Note that 74 'Wolframio' is also called 'Tungsteno' in spanish, mostly in old texts.

Comment: Un momento, un momento!! En esa lista falta el [salchichonio](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Cr-x-RJSnmE)

Comment: @Diego ¿ese es un gas noble?